How to create solana program in native rust for minting fungible tokens like ERC20? I did following code:-
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
clock::Clock,
entrypoint,
entrypoint::ProgramResult,
msg,
program_error::ProgramError,
pubkey::Pubkey,
sysvar::Sysvar,
};
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
pub struct ICOAccount {
pub total_supply: u64,
pub admin: Pubkey,
pub balance: Vec<(Pubkey, u64)>,
pub pre_sale_price: u64,
pub pre_sale_limit: u64,
pub sale_price: u64,
pub sale_limit: u64,
pub sale_start_time: u64,
pub sale_end_time: u64,
pub total_price_earned: u64,
pub pre_sale_account: Vec,
pub sale_account: Vec,
}
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
pub struct PreSaleAccount {
pub address: Pubkey,
pub token_amount: u64,
pub token_price: u64,
pub whitelist_account: bool,
}
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
pub struct SaleAccount {
pub address: Pubkey,
pub token_amount: u64,
pub token_price: u64,
}
impl PreSaleAccount {
pub fn whitelist(&mut self) {
self.whitelist_account = !self.whitelist_account;
}
}
entrypoint!(process_instruction);
pub fn process_instruction(
program_id: &Pubkey,
accounts: &[AccountInfo],
instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
msg!("ICO Program Enter Point");
let account_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
let ico_accounts = next_account_info(account_iter)?;

if ico_accounts.owner != program_id {
    msg!("ICO account does not have correct program id");
    return Err(ProgramError::IncorrectProgramId);
}

let mut ico_state = ICOAccount::try_from_slice(&ico_accounts.data.borrow())?;

match instruction_data[0] {
    0 => {
        intialize_ico(program_id, &mut ico_state, account_iter)?;
    }
    1 => {
        let recipient_account_info = next_account_info(account_iter)?;
        let amount_bytes = instruction_data[1..9].try_into().unwrap();
        let amount = u64::from_le_bytes(amount_bytes);
        mint_tokens(&mut ico_state, &recipient_account_info.key, amount)?;
    }
    2 => {
        pre_sale(&mut ico_state, accounts)?;
    }
    3 => {
        sale(&mut ico_state, accounts)?;
    }
    4 => {
        let account_to_whitelist_info = next_account_info(account_iter)?;
        whitelist_account(&mut ico_state, &account_to_whitelist_info.key)?;
    }
    _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData),
}

ico_state.serialize(&mut &mut ico_accounts.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;

Ok(())

}
pub fn intialize_ico(
program_id: &Pubkey,
ico_state: &mut ICOAccount,
account_iter: &mut std::slice::Iter<'_, AccountInfo>,
) -> ProgramResult {
let admin_account = next_account_info(account_iter)?;
if admin_account.key != program_id {
    msg!("Caller is not the admin");
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

ico_state.admin = *admin_account.key;
ico_state.total_supply = 10000;
ico_state.pre_sale_price = 100;
ico_state.pre_sale_limit = 50;
ico_state.sale_price = 200;
ico_state.sale_limit = 100;
ico_state.sale_start_time = 0;
ico_state.sale_end_time = 100;
ico_state
    .balance
    .push((*admin_account.key, ico_state.total_supply));
Ok(())

}
pub fn mint_tokens(
ico_state: &mut ICOAccount,
recipient_accounts: &Pubkey,
amount: u64,
) -> ProgramResult {
if let Some((_, balance)) = ico_state
.balance
.iter_mut()
.find(|(account, _)| *account == *recipient_accounts)
{
*balance += amount;
return Ok(());
}
ico_state.balance.push((*recipient_accounts, amount));
Ok(())

}
pub fn whitelist_account(
ico_state: &mut ICOAccount,
account_to_whitelist: &Pubkey,
) -> ProgramResult {
for pre_sale_account in &mut ico_state.pre_sale_account {
if &pre_sale_account.address == account_to_whitelist {
pre_sale_account.whitelist();
return Ok(());
}
}
Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData)
}
pub fn pre_sale(ico_state: &mut ICOAccount, accounts: &[AccountInfo]) -> ProgramResult {
let acount_iter: &mut std::slice::Iter<', AccountInfo<'>> = &mut accounts.iter();
let buyer_account = next_account_info(acount_iter)?;
let current_time = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp as u64;
if current_time > ico_state.sale_start_time {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData);
}

let mut is_whiltelisted = false;
let buyer_account_info = buyer_account.key;
for pre_sale_account in &ico_state.pre_sale_account {
    if &pre_sale_account.address == buyer_account_info && pre_sale_account.whitelist_account {
        is_whiltelisted = true;
        break;
    }
}

if !is_whiltelisted {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

let amount_bytes = &buyer_account.data.borrow()[..8];
let amount = u64::from_le_bytes(amount_bytes.try_into().unwrap());
let total_cost = amount * ico_state.pre_sale_price;

if total_cost != buyer_account.lamports() {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

for pre_sale_account in &mut ico_state.pre_sale_account {
    if &pre_sale_account.address == buyer_account_info {
        pre_sale_account.token_amount += amount;
    }
}

**buyer_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= total_cost;

if let Some((_, buyer_balance)) = ico_state
    .balance
    .iter_mut()
    .find(|(account, _)| *account == *buyer_account.key)
{
    *buyer_balance += amount;
} else {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

if let Some((_, admin_balance)) = ico_state
    .balance
    .iter_mut()
    .find(|(account, _)| *account == ico_state.admin)
{
    *admin_balance -= amount;
} else {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

ico_state.total_price_earned += total_cost;

Ok(())

}
pub fn sale(ico_state: &mut ICOAccount, accounts: &[AccountInfo]) -> ProgramResult {
let acount_iter: &mut std::slice::Iter<', AccountInfo<'>> = &mut accounts.iter();
let buyer_account = next_account_info(acount_iter)?;
let buyer_account_info = buyer_account.key;
let current_time = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp as u64;
if current_time < ico_state.sale_start_time
    || ico_state.sale_start_time >= ico_state.sale_end_time
{
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData);
}

let amount_bytes = &buyer_account.data.borrow()[..8];
let amount = u64::from_le_bytes(amount_bytes.try_into().unwrap());
let total_cost = amount * ico_state.sale_price;

if total_cost != buyer_account.lamports() {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

for sale_account in &mut ico_state.sale_account {
    if &sale_account.address == buyer_account_info {
        sale_account.token_amount += amount;
    }
}

**buyer_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= total_cost;

if let Some((_, buyer_balance)) = ico_state
    .balance
    .iter_mut()
    .find(|(account, _)| *account == *buyer_account.key)
{
    *buyer_balance += amount;
} else {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

if let Some((_, admin_balance)) = ico_state
    .balance
    .iter_mut()
    .find(|(account, _)| *account == ico_state.admin)
{
    *admin_balance -= amount;
} else {
    return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
}

ico_state.total_price_earned += total_cost;

Ok(())

}
